# Update a dijit treeWidget node attribute

Tags: tree, dojo

I have found several posts showing how to refresh and display an updated tree, but I still have what must seem a trivial question.

My tree is created using

```
treeStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
    data: {
      identifier: 'id',
      label: 'label',
      items: treeJson 
    }});
treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({ store: treeStore });
treeControl = new dijit.Tree({...});
```

where I have built up my treeJson structure. Each node has a "description" attribute, which is displayed as a tooltip when the mouse hovers over the node.

Now, I'd like to update the "description" value as new data is retrieved.
My question is: how do I update the tree model, so when I do a tree refresh, the new data value is displayed? Given a node in the tree, how do I post my new attribute so that it gets displayed when the tree is refreshed? I don't need to change the structure of the tree in any way, just update a node attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To update the value of the `description` property for each item, or any other property for that matter, you must modify the underlying Observable store rather than modifying the Tree directly.

I created a [simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpdw4h15/4/) demonstrating similar functionality, updating an item's `name` property.

For more information, see the the [reference guide on this topic](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tree.html#how-do-i-update-a-tree-adding-or-deleting-items).